# Detecting IME input before enter pressed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, localization, dom-events, ime

I'm not even sure if this is possible, so apologies if it's a stupid question.

I've set up an `keyup` callback through jQuery to run a function when a user types in an input box. It works fine for English.

However when inputting text in Japanese/Korean/Chinese, the function isn't called until the user confirms their text.

Is it possible to detect that they've started typing, and access their as-yet unfinished text?

I'm thinking maybe it's an OS-level thing so Javascript doesn't have access to it.

**Edit:** I just realised that this works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox (not had a chance to try it on Windows yet). So Chrome calls keyup and it's possible to get the text. But I'm still having the above problem in Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354358) in Firefox, and what browsers *should* be doing [isn't clear](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapi/2008Apr/0034.html).

A possible method for working around this problem is [demonstrated here](https://bug354358.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=240567), where the text field is polled for changes to the text (rather than relying on events).

Answer (score 25):

The **`compositionstart`, `compositionupdate` and `compositionend` events** might be helpful.
They help you detect when IME input is being used.

For example, consider using an IME to type か (ka) in Japanese.
The following events (in the order shown) would be fired:

- <kbd>k</kbd> (IME visible) keydown, **compositionstart**, **compositionupdate**, **compositionend**, input
- <kbd>a</kbd> (IME visible), **compositionstart**, **compositionupdate**, **compositionend**, input
- <kbd>enter</kbd> (IME closed) keydown, input

Notice that the compositon events are only fired when the IME is visible (before <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed). Also notice that the *keypress* event is not fired. This is only fired for non-IME input.

To access the user's unfinished text, you can use the `data` property of the event.

```
$('#input').on('compositionupdate', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

For more info see MDN: [compositionstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionstart), [compositionupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionupdate), [compositionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/compositionend), [InputEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent).

Comment: Changing to keypress worked fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I think that in your `ka` example, there's no compositionend event after the k, only after the a. This event is fired when a letter is finalized.